# Retrieving files with paths with CMake

Tags: cmake

I have a C++ library that is using cmake. The structure of my library looks like this:

```
src/module1/class1.h 
src/module1/class1.cpp 
src/module1/class2.h
src/module1/class2.cpp
src/module2/class3.h
src/module2/class3.cpp
```

etc..

I want to make install rule for my project using INSTALL command. First, i need to retrieve all my headers files:

```
FILE (GLOB_RECURSE ALL_HEADERS "*.h")
```

Next i'm trying to install them to C:\temp:

```
INSTALL(FILES {$ALL_HEADER} DESTINATION "C:\\temp")
```

It works, but resulting directory is following:

```
temp/class1.h
temp/class2.h
temp/class3.h
```

but not is:

```
temp/module1/class1.h
temp/module1/class2.h
temp/module2/class3.h
```

As you see CMake doesn't "remember" folder paths. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of options is using `install(DIRECTORY ...` syntax:

```
install(DIRECTORY src/module1 src/module2 DESTINATION "C:/temp" FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

Comment: It works... but it copies all files, not just "*.h". Seems that PATTERN command doesn't work

Comment: It was need FILES_MATCHING pattern and "/" instead of "\\": install(DIRECTORY src/module1 src/module2 DESTINATION "C:/temp" FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h") . Please update your post and i make my question answered